# Use of “innit” in informal English English

Tags: grammar, british-english, slang

“innit” etymologically started as a contraction of “isn't it?” and can obviously always replace it. I also know it can now replace any negative tag interrogative such as “wasn't he?” or “can't they?” in sentences such as “*He's eaten that, innit?*”  where it replaces “hasn't he?”, but what I wonder about is whether it can also replace positive tags that follow a negative sentence such as:

> He hasn't eaten yet, innit? [<- has he?]

> That can't be right, innit? [<- can it?]

Would these sentence and other similar ones actually be used in informal English English around London by younger speakers stereotyped to use “innit”?

Comment: When you say *obviously always replace it*, you mean in the slangiest of texting?

Comment: @YosefBaskin: No, not just texting, in (very informal) spoken language too.

Comment: Munna look into it.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It's [in the dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/innit) and everything :)

Comment: Yes, it can "He's not eaten, innit?" -> isn't that true? -> that is true -> you must be aware of that -> that is the reason, etc. It is an emphatic

Comment: Obviously the continental influence: “n’est pas” and “nicht war” ( or oder or gel). We will probably loose this colour as part of the Brexit Dividend.

Comment: In Indian English, final _isn't it?_ is an invariable tag like _nicht wahr_. Of course, it's pronounced something like /ɪɖɳɪʈ/, but that could be represented by "innit", given the sloppiness of English eye dialect.

Comment: @David You mean _N'est-**ce** pas?_

Comment: @fev — I imagine so. But spoken it sounds just the same. (Which is how I overcame the poor marks I got for languages at school, and became able to talk to real people.)

Comment: @David Well, it actually does not sound just the same in French... :) I understand grammar or orthography can be stifling sometimes, but I still like them.

Comment: @fev I see you are a translator. Ok it’s your job to be accurate. But I make two points. 1. You knew what I was talking about — a single expression in French and German to ask for affirmation of a statement made. No real English equivalent, except perhaps “right?”.  I communicated. 2. You don’t have to be literate to communicate verbally. Only connect!

Comment: @David I feel you, David :) Sorry if I sound pedantic, I assure you I am not. I find people like you refreshing, and I know exactly what you mean. I was even a teacher once, besides being a translator, so you understand how instinctive my over correctness has become :D

Comment: @fev — Don't get me wrong. I applaud linguistic correctness and have a respect for the literature and culture of the languages I have struggled to learn. But I am aware of my own limitations and those of people like me who have to be in a country and speak to learn a language, and have difficulty doing it academically, especially writing it. As a schoolboy with a science bent, Latin appeared to me the height of mathematical order, but when put on the spot, I would fail to apply the rules I understood. And in French I always avoided Qu'est ce que c'est and inverted subject and verb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138461/discussion-between-fev-and-david).

Comment: @David I think that the origin of "innit" used universally is in communities of people of South Asian origin. Not knowing any South Asian languages I assume that most if not all of those languages have a constuction which is an exact translation of "nicht war" and "qu'est que c'est". I've also noticed that many Welsh people use "isn't it" in a similar manner. However I also think that the coreect translation for "nicht war" and "qu'est que c'est" is actually "is that not so" rather than "isn't it" or "innit". "Isn't it" is part of the whole set of English expressions like "didn't he".

Comment: @BoldBen: Hindi "है ना" ("hai na", "isn't it?") is indeed used like "n'est-ce pas".

Comment: @psmears Obviously "n'est pas?" Comes of doing this when I'm half asleep! The thing is that there is are two universal equivalents of the foreign language phrases equivalent to n'est pas in English which are "is that not so?" and "isn't that right?". English, unlike most other languages, has the context-specific phrases "isn't it?", "don't you?", "haven't I?" and so on which are much more widely used particularly among working class people. I find it rather sad that the context-specific phrases are being undermined by "innit?" when the universal phrases exist.

Answer (score 1):

Most dictionaries still record ***innit*** as an invariant tag (from *isn't it*), as you mention, but it is very true that its use is currently spreading, though it is still considered ***[non-standard](http://www.englicious.org/lesson/tag-questions-innit-0)***, and therefore should not be used in formal cotnexts. I have found a dictionary that already mentions that:

> a way of saying any question tag, such as ‘*don’t you?*’ or ‘*haven’t you?*’
>
> - You got it, innit? ([OxfordLearner'sDict](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/innit))

Ignacio Palacios Martinez, in his article *[Variation, development and pragmatic uses of **innit** in the language of British adults and teenagers](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/english-language-and-linguistics/article/abs/variation-development-and-pragmatic-uses-of-innit-in-the-language-of-british-adults-and-teenagers1/D4A2B9DEE76D942EDC039A7DA5AA1D9B)* published in 2014 in Cambridge's *English Language & Linguistics* speaks precisely of that:

> Findings confirm that ***innit*** is *typical of the language of London teenagers* and has not gone out of use; on the contrary, *its frequency has increased over the last few years*. In contrast, the proportion of tokens found in the language of their adult counterparts is rather marginal.
>
> At present, ***innit*** conserves ***syntactic features of its own***: ***it does not follow the regular question tag formation rules and can represent not only the verb BE but also DO, HAVE and most of the modal verbs***.
>
> - *She love* her chocolate ***innit***?
> - *It was good* ***innit***?
>
> Furthermore, it continues to show a high degree of flexibility in the sentence, occurring not only in final but also in initial and medial positions.
>
> It appears that ***innit*** *should no longer be regarded as a simple invariant tag*. It tends to behave more and more like a ***pragmatic marker*** serving *to express the speaker's attitude to the content of the message*, thus often reflecting the relationship between the participants in the interaction, and also contributing to the organisation of the discourse. In this respect, two new discourse functions of ***innit*** are identified and described: ***emphatic*** and ***text organiser***.

This other [interesting post](http://dialectblog.com/2011/05/12/its-in-the-oed-innit/) defends its legitimacy saying:

> ***Innit*** is a real word (it’s in the OED), just as valid as *isn’t, ain’t* or *shan’t*. Why is there debate about this? ***Innit*** is often used in a grammatically “wrong” manner. But people fill their sentences with far more illogical word uses: for example, the extraneous uses of “like,” “right?” and “you know?” None of these words or phrases are invalidated because of it. Just because the word is used “incorrectly” doesn’t mean it is incorrect in and of itself.

The examples it gives however do not include negative verbs as in your examples:

> - We’re British, innit.
> - She’s well out of order, innit?
> - I was just joking, innit!

Although, listed examples of this particular "ungrammatical" use of this tag at the end of negative sentences are scarce, I would not be surprised if it were used in this way since:

> In Britain and among American Indians, among others, this “*invariant isn’t it*” is reduced to “***innit***,” and may be used even more broadly as a general emphatic exclamation ***at the end of almost any statement***. ([Prof. Paul Brians, Wahshington State University](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/24/isnt-it-innit/))

I managed to find one example in *[Discourse-Pragmatic Variation and Change in English](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Discourse_Pragmatic_Variation_and_Change/AwjPDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=innit%20usage&pg=PA60&printsec=frontcover)*, p. 61:

> I dunno what’s gonna happen if she’s not back. ***Innit***, it shouldn’t be like this. (Tina, 18 y.o.)

Comment: A nice piece of research but, despite all that, I have yet to hear it used by even one of my reasonably well-educated acquaintance. Its use, other than as facetious take-off of lower register speakers, is a marker of lack of, or insensitivity to, formal education. A non-native speaker should use it with great care, preferably only in the company of those who speak in this argot. I know this may sound elitist but it is also realistic.

Comment: @Anton That's what all these articles say basically, that it is dialectal, used mainly by teenagers, and still considered non-standard, so should not be used in formal contexts. Yet the fact that it made it to the dictionaries does say something about the current pulse of the language.

Comment: Here's a link to Catherine Tate performing very chavvy teenager Lauren Cooper on *Royal Variety Performance* for the Queen, who is in attendance. You'll hear her use 'innit' three times (none happening to actually stand for 'isn't it') at 0:28 ('innit' follows her saying, 'It would be a laugh', making 'innit' stand for 'wouldn't it'), 0:45 ('innit' follows another saying, 'She is big time', making 'innit' stand for 'isn't she'), and 1:36 ('innit' follows another saying, 'She is dripping with diamonds', making 'innit' stand for 'isn't she'): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUzPontl0pU .